# How can I split YAML into different files in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have this yaml_file in a variable in python using safe_load from yaml library:

```
domainInfo:
    AdminUserName: '--FIX ME--'
    AdminPassword: '--FIX ME--'
topology:
    Name: 'wld-pil-10'
    ConfigBackupEnabled: true
    AdminServerName: 'wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0'
    DomainVersion: 12.2.1.4.0
    ProductionModeEnabled: true
    ArchiveConfigurationCount: 20
    Cluster:
        'test-bruno-jee-r01a-c01':
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
    Server:
        'wls-pil-10-sa-adm-n0':
            ListenPort: 11030
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n0'
        'test-bruno-jee-r01a-it-c01-m1-n1':
            ListenPort: 10022
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            NMSocketCreateTimeoutInMillis: 30000
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n1'
        'test-bruno-jee-r02a-it-c01-m1-n1':
            ListenPort: 10025
            WeblogicPluginEnabled: true
            ClientCertProxyEnabled: true
            NMSocketCreateTimeoutInMillis: 30000
            Machine: 'wlm-pil-10-n2'
```

In order to split this yaml file I'm trying to put the keys and values in a new dictionary but without success. What am I missing? I know that I need to have a dictionary in some way, do I need to use another module like pyyaml or ruamel?

```
yaml_cluster = {}
yaml_cluster["topology"]["Name"] = yaml_file["topology"]["Name"]
yaml_cluster["topology"]["AdminServerName"] = yaml_file["topology"]["AdminServerName"]
```

Result:

> fatal: [wls-pil-103-sa-adm-n0]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg":
> "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Traceback (most recent
> call last):\n  File
> "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1611083722.9917288-55849-215378473850896/split_yaml.py",
> line 32, in \n    yaml_cluster["topology"]["Name"] =
> yaml_file["topology"]["Name"]\nKeyError: 'topology'\n",
> "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File
> "/tmp/ansible-tmp-1611083722.9917288-55849-215378473850896/split_yaml.py",
> line 32, in ", "    **yaml_cluster["topology"]["Name"] =
> yaml_file["topology"]["Name"]**", **"KeyError: 'topology'"**], "stdout":
> "", "stdout_lines": []}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is because `yaml_cluster["topology"]["Name"]` is assigned a value without either of the keys existing. `yaml_cluster["topology"]` does not exist and you can therefore not assign something to the key `Name`.

Collections module from the standard library provides a class `collections.defaultdict` that gives a key a default value if it doesn't exist. In your case a `defaultdict` with a empty dictionary as default value sets the value of `yaml_cluster["topology]` to `{}` (an empty dict) and the key `Name` can then be assigned with a value to the dictionary as normal.

```
from collections import defaultdict

yaml_cluster = defaultdict(dict) # Specifying dictionary as default value for missing keys
yaml_cluster["topology"]["Name"] = yaml_file["topology"]["Name"]
yaml_cluster["topology"]["AdminServerName"] = yaml_file["topology"]["AdminServerName"]
```

Comment: but now I get something like this when I save my variable in a file: 
`!!python/object/apply:collections.defaultdict
args:
- !!python/name:builtins.dict ''
dictitems:
  topology:
    AdminServerName: wls-pil-103-sa-adm-n0
    Name: wld-pil-103
`

Comment: @shamaN A range of causes could've given that error as it is to vague. I would advise starting a new stackoverflow thread with as much example code as possible and some log files. To help others answer your question as fast as possible also follow the [guide on writing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)